# Hanging MySQL2 connections spun up in EventMachine

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems, eventmachine

I'm running this code from the mysql2 gem docs:

```
require 'mysql2/em'

EM.run do
  client1 = Mysql2::EM::Client.new
  defer1 = client1.query "SELECT sleep(3) as first_query"
  defer1.callback do |result|
    puts "Result: #{result.to_a.inspect}"
  end

  client2 = Mysql2::EM::Client.new
  defer2 = client2.query "SELECT sleep(1) second_query"
  defer2.callback do |result|
    puts "Result: #{result.to_a.inspect}"
  end
end
```

It runs fine, printing the results

```
Result: [{"second_query"=>0}]
Result: [{"first_query"=>0}]
```

but then the script just hangs and never returns to the command line. Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EM.run` will start an EventMachine reactor. That reactor just loops and loops and loops until you somehow tell it to stop. You can manually stop it using `EM.stop`.

In your case, you might want to check for the callback results and stop the reactor when both callbacks fired. Ilya's em-http-request library provides a nice [interface](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request/wiki/Parallel-Requests) for exactly that use case. Might be worth a look.

Comment: Thanks! That makes perfect sense.